# Workflow Terminating

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow-activity

I have a workflow that create tasks once an item is changed. For some reason, it is terminating with message

> "Another instance of the same workflow with the same ActivationInfo is currently executing. Its instance id is *instance-id*.

But once I reran the said workflows, it will generate tasks and will be completed. I googled it but is still at a loss on what's happening. We are using Sharepoint Online.

Have you guys experienced it?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you modifying the same item within the workflow that triggered it?

Comment: Yes. I think that would be causing it to terminate eh?

Comment: Yes, likely to keep itself from getting stuck in an infinite loop of re-triggering itself.

Comment: is there any fix for that? Like, waiting for the item to be saved before trigerring the workflow?

Comment: Well, without knowing all the details of the items in your triggering list or what you are changing, it would be difficult to give specific suggestions, but in general, you want to make the first action in your workflow be a "short circuit" that will purposefully terminate the workflow if its metadata appears to have been modified by your workflow or something other than user updated.  Maybe a specific value you are setting or something that you can check for.

Answer (score 0):

1. Do not modify the item until the workflow is completed.
2. Go to workflow settings to check how many versions of workflow, you could remove previous versions of workflow.

Comment: This particular item has many fields in it that needs to be changed in one go. Is there any actions that will allow the workflow to wait for the changes to be saved before starting again?